# jnz by pointer is not possible in 386 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

This code works:

```
jz jnzover
jmp [esi + 8]
jnzover:
```

Is there a way to write this in one opcode?

When I type `jnz [esi + 8]` it will say "expecting pointer type"

Comment: A quick check of your 386 assembly reference will tell you what operands to jnz are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no support for `r/m16` and `r/m32` operands for `Jcc` opcodes (only `rel16/32`). If you want to branch to an arbitrary (or an absolute) address, you can only do it through `JMP r/m16` and `JMP r/m32` instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Only ever heard of conditional jumps in the zilog z80 chip

ifz-add ax,bx

kinda stuff was in the Ketman Interpeter but it was a macro assembled as

jnz HERE

add ax,bx

HERE

was the assembled code

The entire 8088 range lacks conditional calls and rets

Comment: Huh? The question was about indirect conditional branching.